Concentration inequalities when you know the complete distribution of a discrete random variable.
My understanding of concentration inequalities is that most of them assume that you don't know anything about your random variables other than quantities like your mean or variance or some finite number of higher moments maybe.
Is there any better I can do if I know the exact probability distribution? My $X_j$ are all iid, and draw values $x_{i}$ for $1 \le i \le n$ with probability $\frac{1}{n}$.
The trouble I am having with Hoeffding and Bernstein is that my $x_{i}$ are roughly exponentially distributed, but not exactly. They do actually arise as $e^{y_{i}}$ where my $y_{i}$ are linear-ish / quadratic.

If you know the distributions exactly then you should be able to come up with more bespoke inequalities (or equalities, really!), but how tractable these are will depend on the distribution.
